# How to add Autocompletion for QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

What i want to do is to start typing some data in a table cell and it shows completion suggestions but so far no success.

I tried adding QLineEdit in a cell but is there a way to accomplish that without using QLineEdit as a cellWidget?

### Edit:

Made it work by overriding **QItemDelegate** class

#### Autocomplete_Delegate.h

```
#include <QItemDelegate>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QCompleter>

class Autocomplete_Delegate : public QItemDelegate {
public:
    Autocomplete_Delegate(QObject *parent, QStringList model);
    ~Autocomplete_Delegate();
    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const override;

private:
    QStringList model;
};
```

#### Autocomplete_Delegate..cpp

```
Autocomplete_Delegate::Autocomplete_Delegate(QObject *parent, QStringList model) : QItemDelegate(parent), model(model) {}

Autocomplete_Delegate::~Autocomplete_Delegate() {
    model.clear();
}

QWidget *Autocomplete_Delegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const {
    QWidget *editor = QItemDelegate::createEditor(parent, option, index); //* Create the editor so it looks native to the tablewidget
    QLineEdit *lineEdit = static_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor); //* create a linedit so it behaves like a line edit and cast the editor to line edit
    QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(model, parent); //* make a completer and pass in the wordlist
    completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive); //* set the case senstivity
    lineEdit->setCompleter(completer); //* set the completor on line edit
    return lineEdit;
}

void Autocomplete_Delegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const {
    QString data = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toString(); //* get the data from the model -> the cell
    QLineEdit *lineEdit = static_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
    lineEdit->setText(data); //* set the data in the editor
}
```

Thanks to @eyllanesc for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a role associated with the QTableWidgetItem, and use a delegate to create a QCompleter where your model is established and updated.

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

enum CustomRoles{
    ListCompleterRole = Qt::UserRole + 1000
};

class CompletedDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate{
public:
    using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;
    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const{
        QWidget* editor = QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent, option, index);
        if(QLineEdit *le = qobject_cast<QLineEdit *>(editor)){
            QStringListModel *model = new QStringListModel(le);
            QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(le);
            completer->setModel(model);
            le->setCompleter(completer);
        }
        return editor;
    }
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const{
        QStyledItemDelegate::setEditorData(editor, index);
        if(QLineEdit *le = qobject_cast<QLineEdit *>(editor)){
            if(QCompleter *completer = le->completer()){
                if(QStringListModel *model = qobject_cast<QStringListModel *>(completer->model())){
                    QVariant v = index.data(CustomRoles::ListCompleterRole);
                    if (v.canConvert<QStringList>()){
                        QStringList options = v.value<QStringList>();
                        model->setStringList(options);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QStringList words = {
        "astonishing", 
        "agreement", 
        "appeal", 
        "autonomy", 
        "accompany", 
        "articulate", 
        "article", 
        "amuse", 
        "advertise",
        "admiration"
    };

    QTableWidget w(1, 1);
    CompletedDelegate *delegate = new CompletedDelegate(&w);
    w.setItemDelegate(delegate);

    QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem;
    item->setData(CustomRoles::ListCompleterRole, words); // update options
    w.setItem(0, 0, item);

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the code and how does it behave.

Comment: @awr417h It works for me with QTableWidget in Qt 5.13.1, what do you get when you write "a" in the editor? Are you using the code without modifying it? If you have modified it then try it first without modifications, understand it and then you can try to change it

Comment: @awr417h Then I assume that you are using my code as it is without modifying it, if so, can you tell me what version of Qt you use, what is your OS, etc. What is the ouput of `qDebug() << v;`

Comment: @awr417h mmm, interesting, if you say: *your code works* then my answer is wrong ?, I don't think so. My answer is correct as you indicate but another problem is that you do not imply well in your project, and how your project is impossible for me to help you. If you want help provide a [MRE], or share your project via github to see where the problem is